# Oracle database space

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

The sum of `sm$ts_free.bytes` and `sm$ts_used.bytes` is not equal to `sm$ts_alloc.bytes`.

What can be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 2):

There is [a discussion about these views](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=993146) in the OTN forum. It seems the difference between `sm$ts_free.bytes + sm$ts_used.bytes` and `sm$ts_alloc.bytes` is a constant overhead. It is probably used to store tablespace header information.

Comment: Its means for all databases, this gap will exist but in my case another database is not showing this difference (no diff betwwenn sum of sm$ts_free.bytes + sm$ts_used.bytes and  sm$ts_alloc.bytes). Why it showing for one and not for another?

Comment: @user269484: well, these views are not documented in the 10g version, they might be deprecated. Since they are not documented, the behaviour may vary between releases and between platforms.